# Не могу понять как исправить проблему с позиционированием

Tags: html, css

Только начал учить css и html и столкнулся с проблемой. Пишу текст в блоке и из за него начинают съезжать сами блоки.

[image: Боксы съезжают]

[image: ..]

css свойства:

```
.header2_modules {
  margin-top: 205px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #3f2aff;
}
.div_ul {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.ul_modules {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.li_modules {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 572px;
  height: 505px;
}
.li1 {
  background-image: url(../img/photo-1530435460869-d13625c69bbf\ copy.png);
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: 572px 180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.li2 {
  background-image: url(../img/2photo-1530435460869-d13625c69bbf\ copy.png);
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: 572px 180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.li3 {
  background-image: url(../img/3photo-1530435460869-d13625c69bbf\ copy.png);
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: 572px 180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.li4 {
  background-image: url(../img/4photo-1530435460869-d13625c69bbf\ copy.png);
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: 572px 180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.li_text_modules:not(:last-child) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.li_text_modules:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: что за странная разметка? по правилам внутри `ul` могут только `li` лежать

Comment: кроме css нужно добавить пример твоего html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых - прижмите все блоки к верху.
Во-вторых - ограничьте высоту всех блоков через `max-height`
В-третьих - либо решите, что  вас во всех блоках не более N-строк, либо, если строк много и они уходят за нижний край - сделайте или прокрутку внутри блока, или красивое затемнение половины строки уходящей под нижний край

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: не за что. рад, если помог :)